# Using rules of inference draw conclusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I was about to leave for my job and came to know that the keys of my cars are lost. I only know the following scenario:

- I was not reading the newspaper in the kitchen or I didn’t place my keys on the kitchen table.
- I was reading the newspaper in the kitchen.
- If  I was having my breakfast, my keys are on the kitchen table,
- If  I was not having my breakfast, I was sitting on sofa.
- If I was sitting on sofa, my keys are in the lounge.

Where are the keys?

this is what is understand but cannot conclude:

let p:i was reading newspaper in the kitchen

let q:I placed my keys on the kitchen table

let r:I was having my breakfast

let s:I was sitting on sofa

let t:my keys are in the lounge

these are the hypothesis from the statements but i don't know how to conclude:

¬pv¬q

p

r→q

¬r→s

s→t

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: hey, ok I mentioned how far I was able to solve it.

Comment: Qhat are p,v,q,r, s and t in your solution?

Comment: now mentioned them.

Answer (score 2):

The keys are in the lounge. You can translate the sentences into

- $\neg A \lor \neg B$ (with $A = $ reading newspaper in kitchen and $B =$ didn't place keys on kitchen table)
- $A$

This implies $\neg B$.

- $C \implies B$ (with $C =$ having breakfast)

This implies $\neg C$.

- $\neg C \implies D$ (with $D =$ sitting on sofa)

This implies $D$.

- $D \implies E$ (with $E = $ keys are in lounge)

This implies $E$.